# In Elementary OS 6.0 upgrade

Tags: updates

In the newer version of Elementary OS can you do:
do-release upgrade from the terminal like in Ubuntu or some similiar command
to upgrade to a newer version of Elementary OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elementary OS 6 has to be installed as a fresh install. No upgrade option from eOS 5 that I am aware of.

Comment: Are they working on a Path like in Ubuntu?

Comment: I do not know. Hopefully someone familiar with what's going on inside the project can comment.